# Why can't I move out of a HashMap in Rust?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

In this minimal reproducible example, we have a hashmap with values that contain a `Vec<i32>`, and as far as I know, `Vec<T>` does not implement `Copy`, so it will be moved anytime it needs.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct MyStruct {
    id: i32,
    vec_number: Vec<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut hashmap: HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>> = HashMap::new();

    let a = MyStruct {
        id: 1,
        vec_number: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };

    let b = MyStruct {
        id: 2,
        vec_number: vec![1, 2, 3],
    };

    let first_vec = vec![a, b];
    
    for strct in first_vec {
        hashmap.insert(strct.id, strct.vec_number);
    }

    let second_vec : Vec<i32> = *hashmap.get(&2).unwrap(); // error here
}
```

The error I get is:

```
cannot move out of a shared reference
move occurs because value has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I understand the part that says that `Vec<T>` from the `hashmap` will be moved to `second_vec` (the "move out of a shared reference" part). However, what I don't get is: why is this an error, since I will not use `hashmap` anymore in the scope? In my understanding, this move would be a problem only if I referenced the moved value somewhere else in the code.

I've heard that it is to enforce users to use `remove()`, which does the same as the code above, but in a more idiomatic way (since we don't have to derefence the value, like it happens with `hashmap.get()`).

Is this true? What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: "What is the reason for this behavior?" That the type system doesn't allow for it. It doesn't matter that you're not going to use the hashmap anymore, as far as the type system is concerned the value still belongs to the hashmap, and `HashMap::get` only returns a reference to it.

Comment: Ugh, I don't want to imagine a world where I have to rely on context to determine if `get` can move an item or not. Instead it's as simple as "is the type in the signature `&T`" then you can't move, is it `T` then you can.

Comment: In fact you will use `hashmap` again in the scope: it will be dropped implicitly on the closing brace, and will then use the item you just took from it (so that it can drop it too).

Comment: One possible way around would be to clone the vector: `let second_vec : Vec<i32> = (*hashmap.get(&2).cloned().unwrap()).to_vec();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust is a strongly typed language, and that's a design decision to prevent people from doing things which result in undefined behaviour or which are memory unsafe in safe code.

Part of that is ownership: when you have a `T`, you own it and can do with it as you please, but when you have a `&T`, then you're only borrowing it and someone else owns it.

When you use the `get` method, you get only a reference, and thus, you can't move the underlying `T` (in this case, a `Vec<i32>`).  If it's `Copy`, which `Vec<i32>` is not, you can trivially copy it into a new `T`, but otherwise, even if the owner of the reference is about to go away, you can't move out of the reference.  If you had a `&mut T`, you could move out of the reference provided you replaced it with something else, such as by using `std::mem::take`, but non-mutable references are, well, immutable.

The reason for this is that this produces simple, easy-to-reason-about behaviour, and it is simple and efficient to implement.  It also lets people write code that, for example, prevents removing items from a collection, which may be desirable in some cases.

If you want to take ownership of the item from the old `HashMap`, then you have to remove it first.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood it correctly: I can never "move out" of a `&T`, is it? 
If I want to move a value, I have to do it directly, instead of taking a reference and dereferencing it? It seems to be the case, at least in this example I tried: https://pastebin.com/Tp4GWK4x

Comment: You can't move out of either `&T` or `&mut T`. The only indirection type you can move out of is `Box<T>.